# How do I get the count of a certain emoji reaction on a message in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I am creating a poll command, and I am trying to get the reaction counts on a single emoji. And when I looked up the message earlier today, it returned the message data, with the `reactions` collection showing. However, when I looked up the reactions collection, it returned `undefined`. After a lot more debugging and attempts, it only returns a list of all the messages in the channel.

```
const embedMessage = await channel.messages.fetch(row.get('messageID')); //row.get(messageID) is just looking at a database for the stored messageID, I checked and the database is storing that correctly.
const embedMessageReacts = embedMessage.reactions; //This returns 'undefined'

//I also have the original 'embed' constant cached from the original embed message sending higher in the code but it no longer shows up as anything.
//The 'channel' constant works as normal.
//Also, the collection cannot be empty as the bot itself reacts to the message I am getting. Meaning, the message already has at least 2 reactions on it (the minimum for the command to work causes there to be at least 2 reactions)
//Lastly, it is not listening for reactions (although there is a listener for when the message containing these reactions is sent), so I have to look it up manually.
//Instead, these run when a certain time has elapsed.
//Hopefully there is a solution because this issue has taken up 2 days of time.
```

Answer (score 0):

Reactions are not catched anymore.
You'll have to catch them before using.
Like this:

```js
if(!embedMessage){ return(false); }
const embedMessageReacts = embedMessage.reactions.cache;
```

You can count the Emoji easily

```js
let Heart = embedMessage.reactions.cache.get('♥️').count;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if that works later today and will let you know.